# Looping through NodeList Removes Element

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script where I want to change "br" to ", br by" in a NodeList.  The code is:

```
const captions = document.querySelectorAll('.ae-overlay-caption');
const br = document.createElement("br");
for (i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
    captions[i].firstElementChild.replaceWith(",", br, " by");
    };
```

When I check the NodeList before running this script, each node has a "br" for firstElementChild. After running the script, the br's for the first x nodes are removed, and only the last node is updated.  You can see the problem here: https://editart2020.crooked.media/collection/fundamentos/. Mouse over the images. Only the last one works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `replaceWith` adds the same element in each loop iteration.

As a DOM element can only be present at one location in the DOM, in the n-th iteration it will remove the element from the (n-1)th caption and add it to the n-th caption. Therefore, at the end of the loop, only the last caption will contain the element.

Move the `createElement` inside the loop, to generate one element per interation.

Comment: That worked. But I don't know what you mean by "single element can only be present once in the DOM,". Many thanks!

Comment: Pardon my wording. If you create a new DOM node using `createElement`, this element can only be present at a **single location** within the DOM at any one time.

Comment: Got it! appreciate the explanation.